# How to insert zeros in a data frame of R

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe

I have following data.frame, DF
*DF is already in R. we Do not need to load it in r using read.csv or something*

```
            timeStamp count
1 2014-01-15 14:30:00     2
2 2014-01-15 16:30:00     3
3 2014-01-15 17:00:00     2
4 2014-01-15 17:15:00     1
```

I have an "independent seq of timestamps", say `tmpSeq` from `2014-01-15 14:00:00` to `2014-01-22 13:00:00`. I want to get a **List** of counts from this data.frame and insert zeros for `timeStamp` not present in data.frame but in the `tmpSeq`

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example and show what you have so far tried.

Comment: Thanks guys. The merge function actually helped.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your sequence is in 15 minute increments:

```
DF <- data.frame(timeStamp=as.POSIXct(c("2014-01-15 14:30:00","2014-01-15 16:30:00",
                                        "2014-01-15 17:00:00","2014-01-15 17:15:00")),
                 count=c(2,3,2,1))


tmpSeq <- seq(as.POSIXct("2014-01-15 14:00:00"),
              as.POSIXct("2014-01-22 13:00:00"), by="15 mins")

DF <- merge(DF, data.frame(timeStamp=tmpSeq, count=0), all=TRUE)
```

should do it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you are looking for is a 'merge'. Look at this post: [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-data-frames-in-r-inner-outer-left-right)

You need a right outer join ( if you make tmpSeq as your right data frame)

Edit:
Adding the merge statement in the answer to make the answer clearer :

```
Right outer: merge(x = DF, y = data.frame(timeStamp=tmpSeq, count=0), all.y=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it is better to work with some ts packages when you deal with time series objects. Using `xts` package you can use `rbind` to merge 2 times series.

- First I create the short time series
- I generate the long ts assuming it is regular ts with 15 mins interval
- I merge the 2 series using `rbind`

Here my code:

```
library(xts)
dat = as.xts(read.zoo(text='
time Stamp count        ## a small hack here to read your data
1 2014-01-15 14:30:00     2
2 2014-01-15 16:30:00     3
3 2014-01-15 17:00:00     2
4 2014-01-15 17:15:00     1',
         header=TRUE,
         index=1:2,
         format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',tz=''))

## generate the long ts
tmpSeq <-
seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct('2014-01-15 14:00:00'),
    as.POSIXct('2014-01-22 13:00:00'),by = '15 mins')
tmpSeq <- 
xts(x=rep(0,length(tmpSeq)),tmpSeq)

## insert dat values in tmpSeq
rbind(tmpSeq,dat)
```